# I have a hard time understanding the purpose of a "backing property"

Tags: java, kotlin

I am learning Kotlin right now. For context, I am a Java developer for +10 years.

I stumbled upon the concept of *backing properties*. As I understand it, the problem to be solved is this: I have a property in a class. I want this property to be mutable and visible only in the containing class, so I declare it as `private var`. The property should only be modified in the containing class, but it should be readable outside the class. So, the Kotlin docs propose something like this:

```kotlin
private var _word = "test"
val word: String
   get() = _word
```

This works and fulfills the above requirements, but this looks a bit odd, for a Java developer. In Java, we only need 1 field (there is no such thing as a property in Java):

```
private String word = "test";

public String getWord() {
   return word;
}
```

AFAIK, same result.

Today I learned that in Kotlin, I simply can make a setter private. So what about this Kotlin code:

```
var word = "test"
     private set
```

All requirements fulfilled, much more concise code.

Im I missing something? **Why do I need a backing property?**

Comment: *In Java, we only need 1 field* and a function

Comment: My guess would be that the former compiles to a private field and a getter method, while the latter compiles to a public or package-private field. Perhaps the more important difference is that the backing property can be lazily initialised, though.

Comment: @Tim – If you want to nitpick, in Java we need a field and a *method*. Although for my understanding, the sample that the thread owner is wondering about defines a function (or method), too – in addition to the two fields (or properties …)

Comment: backing property is used for cases when you need some mutable object (e.g. `MutableList`) inside the class, but you expose some narrower type or immutable interface (`List`) outside

Comment: Adding to what @IR42 said. Note that in the example from the official docs (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-properties) both properties have different types. Kotlin doesn't provide a way to expose narrower type publicly and wider type internally and this is one of reasons to use a backing prop. Another is property delegates.

Answer (score 6):

*(This answer starts with some general info about Kotlin properties, as there seems to be general confusion about them.)*

The main conceptual difference between Kotlin and Java is that **in Java, the fundamental thing is the field, while in Kotlin the fundamental thing is the accessor method(s)**.

So in Java, you define a field. You can then define explicit getter and/or setter methods for it, if needed. The language doesn't have a concept of ‘property’, nor does it define any explicit connection between the accessors and the field; but there's a long-standing convention in the accessor method names (deriving originally from [JavaBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans)) that almost everyone follows.

This is clear, but long-winded. And because it's only a convention, the language doesn't force you to match fields with accessors: you can have accessors with different types, setters without getters and vice versa, or even accessors with no field. (Some of those things are desirable, but others are more likely to cause bugs and confusion!)

Kotlin, however, takes the view that the accessors are the important thing. (This is an example of the general principle that you should program to the interface, not caring about how it may be implemented.) In effect, a [property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html) *is* its accessor(s). As long as you have a getter method, then you can get the property's value; and as long as you have a setter method, then you can set it too.

Because getters and setters are usually trivial, Kotlin defines them implicitly unless you tell it otherwise. So when you write:

```
val myProperty = 1
```

then Kotlin creates:

- A private field called `myProperty`, with the type inferred as `Int`, and initialised to the value 1.
- A getter method called `getMyProperty()`, with public scope (as that's the default), returning an `Int`.

That's just what you'd do in Java, only more concise.

What's different is that **whenever you refer to the property, you're calling the accessor method, *not* accessing the field directly**. (That's why it's called a [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-fields) — its only purpose is for the accessor(s) to use.)

Of course, the effect is identical unless you override the accessor. For example:

```
val myProperty = 1
    get() {
        LOG.info("Getting value of myProperty = $field")
        return field
    }
```

(`field` is a special keyword within getters and setters, referring to their backing field.)

As before, this generates a field and a getter method; but the getter method is specified in the code and not autogenerated.

(I haven't referred to mutable properties or setters, but the principle there is the same: if the property is a `var`, then you get an autogenerated or explicit setter method too. One Java possibility that Kotlin *doesn't* support is write-only properties, where some scope can see a setter but no getter. But those are rarely used; you can always use a normal method to set them, which is probably clearer.)

There's one more case to consider. In Java, a getter method can exist on its own, without a corresponding field. (It must then get its value from some other source — maybe by performing a calculation on other fields, or getting it from another object, or even using a hard-coded value.)

You can do the same in Kotlin, by overriding the getter (and setter, if mutable) and *not* referring to the `field`, e.g.:

```
val myProperty: Int
    get() = someOtherObject.someOtherProperty
```

In this case, there would be no point in generating a field, because it would never be used! So Kotlin recognises this and generates *only* the accessor method(s).

It's still a property, because it still has accessor method(s), and the rest of the code can't see any difference. Whether it has a backing field or not is purely an implementation detail.

---

This question is asking about a ‘backing *property*’. The [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-properties) use that term for a separate, private property which ‘shadows’ an existing one, as shown in this question. (Thanks to cactustictacs for the reference.)

There are specific situations where a backing property can be useful. For example, suppose you need to refer to a specific type within the class, but expose only a supertype publicly; the private property could be of the specific type, and then the public one could be of the supertype.

However, that's *not* needed simply to restrict the visibility of a setter method: as the question demonstrates, that can be done explicitly (e.g. by adding `private set` to the property definition).

(In my experience, backing properties are needed very rarely.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations. Made some things clearer, especially the motivation of the Kotlin devs for using the concept of a property.

And yes, I understand that there is a big difference in the terms *backing field* and *backing property*. Before posting my question, the concept of the *backing field* was quite clear to me, but not the concept of the *backing property*.

Comment: I don't think ‘backing property’ is a commonly-used term in Kotlin — probably because they're rarely needed — and so people might use it in slightly different ways. (I didn't fully realise you were drawing that specific distinction in the question!)

Comment: @gidds "backing property" is how the docs refer to it: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-properties

Comment: @cactustictacs Ah, well spotted! I didn't realise there was an official definition. (Though I still suspect most developers aren't aware of it…) I'll update my answer with that, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, there's no reason to do this:

```kotlin
private var _word = "test"
val word: String
   get() = _word
```

Because you can just do this:

```kotlin
var word = "test"
    private set
```

Just like in Java with a private field and a getter method, you can choose later to change getter logic without breaking external code. In Java you could choose to do something more complicated than use a single private backing field. Maybe calculate something involving multiple backing fields, etc. In Kotlin, you can come back later and change it to use other backing properties later if it gets more complicated, and change only the getter implementation.

1. The most common reason I've seen to use a backing property is so you can return a less specific type in your public property:

```kotlin
private val _myList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
val myList: List<String> get() = _myList
```

This code helps prevent outside classes from mutating the returned list.

There is an experimental feature that will eventually be available that will likely eliminate this use case for backing properties. The feature is called *explicit backing fields*. You can declare that the backing field of a property to be a more specific type, and then within the class the more specific type is known and usable, for example:

```kotlin
// Only available as an experimental feature when enabling 
// K2 compiler as of Kotlin 1.8.20:
val myList: List<String>
    field = mutableListOf()
```

2. Another reason to have a backing property is simply when there isn't a one-to-one correspondence between what you're returning and how it is stored or generated. For example:

```kotlin
private val myRandom = Random(1234)
val aNumber: Int get() = myRandom.nextInt(100)
```

3. You might want to compute a property each time it’s accessed instead of storing it and trying to keep it in sync with what it’s dependent on.

```
data class SomeClass(
    var temperatureC: Double
) {
    val temperatureK: Double
        get() = temperatureC + 273.15
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the many details. I now understand the use case for a backing property: returning a less specific type. That makes sense. 

Answer (score 1):

One other use for backing properties is to allow you to store a `null` value internally, but expose a non-null type, and provide some fallback value (which you might not want to store, if null has a specific meaning).

Here's the example from [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-properties):

```
private var _table: Map<String, Int>? = null
public val table: Map<String, Int>
    get() {
        if (_table == null) {
            _table = HashMap() // Type parameters are inferred
        }
        return _table ?: throw AssertionError("Set to null by another thread")
    }
```

What's happening here is your typical singleton `getInstance()`-style accessor, where if the object isn't instantiated yet, you create and store it before returning it. Unlike a `lazy` delegate, it's internally a `var` meaning it can be replaced with a new `Map`, or `null` in this example (with some handler code anticipating a potential concurrency issue)

The caller sees none of this though - outwardly it's just a plain `val` that returns a non-null `Map`, accessed like any other property, with no need to handle a potential null. All that nullability is abstracted away, it's an internal detail.

You'd have to do the same thing in Java (let's say if you wanted to use the `@NonNull` annotation on your getter), creating an internal variable and wrangling its state. It's just that in Kotlin, you get a basic backing field "for free" (if you even need one) and it's only if that isn't adequately needs-suiting that you need to start creating and poking at properties yourself