# Backing property vs. getter for returning a less specific type

Tags: kotlin

This is a follow up question to my previous question [I have a hard time understanding the purpose of a "backing property"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71032860/i-have-a-hard-time-understanding-the-purpose-of-a-backing-property)

I understand that sometimes, we want to to have a private mutable list inside a class, and expose an immutable list to outside classes. Like this:

```
class Demo {
    private val _myList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    val myList: List<String> get() = _myList
}

fun main() {
    val list = Demo().myList
}
```

In this case, `list` is an immutable list, as desired.

But what about this code:

```
class Demo {
    private val myList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

    fun getList(): List<String> = myList.toList()
}

fun main() {
    val list = Demo().getList()
}
```

In this case, we don't have an extra property, and `list` is also an immutable list. This is kind of *the Java way* of doing this.

What's the real difference between the two?

Comment: you don't need to call `.toList()` in the second example, then there will be no difference, except for the difference in access to properties/functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
    private val _myList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    val myList: List<String> get() = _myList
```

gives you a reference to `_myList`, but exposed as the immutable `List` supertype. It basically makes it a read-only view of the list.

But this:

```
    private val myList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    fun getList(): List<String> = myList.toList()
```

is creating a *new list* every time you call it. You get a read-only **copy** of the current internal list. You won't see any changes to the original's contents unless you access that property again (i.e. call its getter) to get a new copy of the list.

Comment: That nails it for me. Understood, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be in the Java-style `getList()` method. You're calling the extension function `toList()` every time the method is called. The code for that method:

```
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.toList(): List<T> {
    if (this is Collection) {
        return when (size) {
            0 -> emptyList()
            1 -> listOf(if (this is List) get(0) else iterator().next())
            else -> this.toMutableList()
        }
    }
    return this.toMutableList().optimizeReadOnlyList()
}
```

I don't know how efficient these underlying calls are, but this seems like a lot of unnecessary function calls and conversions inside a getter method.