# "Properties declared in interfaces can't have backing fields, and therefore accessors declared in interfaces can't reference them"

Tags: kotlin

link: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/interfaces.html#properties-in-interfaces

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plfNA.png)

This description "Properties declared in interfaces can't have backing fields, and therefore accessors declared in interfaces can't reference them", can you provide a counterexample? Does it mean that the properties in the interface cannot have set accessors? Does this restriction also apply to implementing classes?

This description "Properties declared in interfaces can't have backing fields, and therefore accessors declared in interfaces can't reference them", can you provide a counterexample? Does it mean that the properties in the interface cannot have set accessors? Does this restriction also apply to implementing classes?

Comment: Why is this question repeating the same thing twice?

Comment: And which aspect of the behavior are you referring to when you say "this restriction"? Be clear and specific as to what the question is. (Are you asking if implementing classes can refer to properties declared in interfaces?)

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71033952/10134209) help?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is the question. Documentation basically says that if we provide an implementation of a property at the interface level, then it can only reference other properties or functions, because interfaces can't have fields.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In the process of learning, I read the document saying that field cannot be used in the accessor, but I can't think of a counterexample. Only this problem.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is just a contract. You can't instantiate an interface and it isn't a class. By itself, it cannot declare properties whose **default implementations** have backing fields. Another way to think of it is that the default implementation of an interface property cannot store any state.

This restriction does not extend to classes that implement the interface. Classes can store state and use backing fields.

A property has a backing field if you give it an initializer using the `=` sign.

```
val x: Int = 0 // can't initialize a property like this in an interface
```

Therefore, **if** (it's optional) you give an interface property a default implementation, it cannot have an initializer. You must define it using a custom getter (and setter for `var`s), and these getters and setters cannot use a backing `field`.

You **can** use setters in the default implementation of an interface property, but it cannot access `field`. It's hard to think of a good example of actually doing this. In practice, it's not often that you even define a `var` in an interface, much less want to give it a default implementation.

Comment: You could accept the answer if it answered your question.