# What is actual advantage of backing property in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, backing-field

I recently started working on Kotlin getters and setters and thereby landed on topic of Backing Properties in Kotlin.
I am aware of the concept of Backing Field in Kotlin.
I was refereeing to a book called Kotlin in depth by Aleksei Sedunov, in which the author says-

> If you need to access a field of a property inside a class in which
> it's declared, you can use backing properties.

While reading the book, I came across [this](https://proandroiddev.com/backing-properties-in-kotlin-cb78dfebfd90) medium article posting the code:

```
class Human {
    private val _age: Int = 20
    val age: Int
        get() {
            return _age
        }

     val printAge = {
         println("Age is: $_age")
     }
}
```

My question is, what is actual advantage of defining a backing property where we can, rather, access the actual variable itself using `this` inside the class ? Like, in the `printAge` function, rather than defining the backing property and then using it, couldn't have we just done this.age ?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71032860/10134209)?

Comment: That's a bad example of using a backing property because it accomplishes nothing. The linked question above has a similar bad example. My answer on that question has examples of two different situations where you need a backing property.

Comment: @Tenfour04 where is your answer ?

Comment: Common use case of backing property is hiding its actual (usually mutable) type like public `StateFlow` being backed by a private `MutableStateFlow`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71035232/506796